# Why is my grid row / grid item hidden, when there's no content in it?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to program a calculator for school using css grid. Please refer to my codepen below. Why is my `#result` div hidden, when there's no content in it? When I put in any text it is visible. What do I do to make it visible even if there is no text in it? Thanks

https://codepen.io/Codpenio/pen/NWPKRYy

```css
#background {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "result result result result" "delete delete modulo plus" "seven eight nine minus" "four five six multiply" "one two three divide" "zero comma equal equal";
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.btn {
  border: 0;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.number {
  color: white;
  background-color: #555555;
}

.operator {
  color: white;
  background-color: #355d77;
}

.delete {
  color: white;
  background-color: #ab002d;
}

.equal {
  color: white;
  background-color: #1f7a29;
}

#result {
  grid-area: result;
  background-color: #464646;
  color: #ebebeb;
  font-family: "Courier New";
  text-align: right;
}

#delete {
  grid-area: delete;
}

#modulo {
  grid-area: modulo;
}

#plus {
  grid-area: plus;
}

#minus {
  grid-area: minus;
}

#divide {
  grid-area: divide;
}

#multiply {
  grid-area: multiply;
}

#comma {
  grid-area: comma;
  background-color: #355d77;
  color: white;
}

#equal {
  grid-area: equal;
}

#zero {
  grid-area: zero;
}

#one {
  grid-area: one;
}

#two {
  grid-area: two;
}

#three {
  grid-area: three;
}

#four {
  grid-area: four;
}

#five {
  grid-area: five;
}

#six {
  grid-area: six;
}

#seven {
  grid-area: seven;
}

#eight {
  grid-area: eight;
}

#nine {
  grid-area: nine;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="background">
  <div id="result"></div>
  <button id="delete" class="delete btn">Del</button>
  <button id="modulo" value="%" class="btn operator opera-bg fall-back">%</button>
  <button id="plus" value="+" class="btn operator opera-bg value align">+</button>

  <button id="seven" value="7" class="btn number num-bg num first-child">7</button>
  <button id="eight" value="8" class="btn number num-bg num">8</button>
  <button id="nine" value="9" class="btn number num-bg num">9</button>
  <button id="minus" value="-" class="btn operator opera-bg">-</button>

  <button value="4" class="btn number num-bg num first-child">4</button>
  <button value="5" class="btn number num-bg num">5</button>
  <button value="6" class="btn number num-bg num">6</button>
  <button value="*" class="btn operator opera-bg">x</button>

  <button id="one" value="1" class="btn number num-bg num first-child">1</button>
  <button id="two" value="2" class="btn number num-bg num">2</button>
  <button id="three" value="3" class="btn number num-bg num">3</button>
  <button id="divide" value="/" class="btn operator opera-bg">/</button>

  <button id="zero" value="0" class="btn number zero" id="delete">0</button>
  <button id="comma" value="." class="btn num-bg comma fall-back">.</button>
  <button id="equal" value="=" class="btn equal align">=</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not hidden but empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use min-height or insert a 0 :

```css
#background {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "result result result result" "delete delete modulo plus" "seven eight nine minus" "four five six multiply" "one two three divide" "zero comma equal equal";
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.btn {
  border: 0;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.number {
  color: white;
  background-color: #555555;
}

.operator {
  color: white;
  background-color: #355d77;
}

.delete {
  color: white;
  background-color: #ab002d;
}

.equal {
  color: white;
  background-color: #1f7a29;
}

#result {
  grid-area: result;
  background-color: #464646;
  color: #ebebeb;
  font-family: "Courier New";
  text-align: right;
  min-height: 1.6em;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

#delete {
  grid-area: delete;
}

#modulo {
  grid-area: modulo;
}

#plus {
  grid-area: plus;
}

#minus {
  grid-area: minus;
}

#divide {
  grid-area: divide;
}

#multiply {
  grid-area: multiply;
}

#comma {
  grid-area: comma;
  background-color: #355d77;
  color: white;
}

#equal {
  grid-area: equal;
}

#zero {
  grid-area: zero;
}

#one {
  grid-area: one;
}

#two {
  grid-area: two;
}

#three {
  grid-area: three;
}

#four {
  grid-area: four;
}

#five {
  grid-area: five;
}

#six {
  grid-area: six;
}

#seven {
  grid-area: seven;
}

#eight {
  grid-area: eight;
}

#nine {
  grid-area: nine;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="background">
  <div id="result"></div>
  <button id="delete" class="delete btn">Del</button>
  <button id="modulo" value="%" class="btn operator opera-bg fall-back">%</button>
  <button id="plus" value="+" class="btn operator opera-bg value align">+</button>

  <button id="seven" value="7" class="btn number num-bg num first-child">7</button>
  <button id="eight" value="8" class="btn number num-bg num">8</button>
  <button id="nine" value="9" class="btn number num-bg num">9</button>
  <button id="minus" value="-" class="btn operator opera-bg">-</button>

  <button value="4" class="btn number num-bg num first-child">4</button>
  <button value="5" class="btn number num-bg num">5</button>
  <button value="6" class="btn number num-bg num">6</button>
  <button value="*" class="btn operator opera-bg">x</button>

  <button id="one" value="1" class="btn number num-bg num first-child">1</button>
  <button id="two" value="2" class="btn number num-bg num">2</button>
  <button id="three" value="3" class="btn number num-bg num">3</button>
  <button id="divide" value="/" class="btn operator opera-bg">/</button>

  <button id="zero" value="0" class="btn number zero" id="delete">0</button>
  <button id="comma" value="." class="btn num-bg comma fall-back">.</button>
  <button id="equal" value="=" class="btn equal align">=</button>
</div>
```

---

To insert 0 you can use the `:empty` pseudo-class: `#result:empty:before {content:'0';}`

Answer (score 1):

You've defined the grid using `grid-template-areas`, which works well in your set-up.

The problem is that you didn't define `grid-template-rows`, which means that each row is sized by `grid-auto-rows`, that has a default value of `auto`, or content-based size (see reference below).

So, your `#results` row, when it has no content, simply collapses to a zero height.

You can either set a height or min-height on the `#results` item, as already proposed in other answers to this question, or define a height on the first row of the grid.

Add this to your code:

```
#background {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "result result result result"
                       "delete delete modulo plus"
                       "seven eight nine minus"
                       "four five six multiply"
                       "one two three divide"
                       "zero comma equal equal";
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px; /* new */
}
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/asdflj/pen/rNaByJR)

Now the first row has a defined height. The remaining rows have content-based height.

---

> [§ 7.1. The Explicit
>   Grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#explicit-grids)
>
> Any rows / columns defined by `grid-template-areas` but not sized by
>   `grid-template-rows` / `grid-template-columns` take their size from the
>   `grid-auto-rows` / `grid-auto-columns` properties.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description! This worked our perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about CSS grid, but what you can do it assign a minimum height to the #result and that will work just fine.

```
#result {
 grid-area: result;
 background-color: #464646;
 color: #ebebeb;
 font-family: "Courier New";
 text-align: right;
 min-height:59px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the default CSS value of `height` and `width` is `auto`, it wouldn't be consumed space (invisible) when there has no content inside the `<div>`.

Just remember to initialize the CSS for `height` and `width` to `<div>` tag.
For your case, try to fix the CSS of `height` will do.